# How to minimze quad count in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, opengl-es-2.0

I'm looking at increasing performance in a SpriteKit application. I noticed in iOS 8 that Apple has introduced a debug property called `showsQuadCount` to `SKView`. Their description on the property says that a lower number is usually better. When I enabled it, I'm horrified to find out that the quad count is a 1 to 1 mapping to my node count! If I have 1000 nodes on screen, the quad count is 1000! Can someone explain to me why this might be? How does SpriteKit determine how many quads it should use to render a scene?

I can post code if it will help, but at this point I'm not even sure what to post. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple: display fewer nodes. 1000 nodes on the screen is **a lot**!

If you cut the number of nodes down by 800 you could reduce the quad count by 80%.

Each node (on the screen) requires one quad (two triangles). There's nothing you can do to *optimize* quad count except drawing fewer quads (aka nodes).

Comment: Ah thank you, so the 1:1 correlation is correct. I assumed that this was not right.